# python pyparsing a delimted list

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse a delimited list, but only getting the first element. Here is my code:

```
point = Literal('.')
e = CaselessLiteral('E')
plusorminus = Literal('+') | Literal('-')
number = Word(nums)
integer = Combine( Optional(plusorminus) + number )
floatnumber = Combine( integer +
                       Optional( point + Optional(number) ) +
                       Optional( e + integer )
                 )


x = Word("0-100") + Suppress("(") + floatnumber + Suppress(")")
y = delimitedList(x)


text = "1(39.75), 2(39.75), 3(39.75), 4(39.75)"

try:
    match = y.searchString(text)

except ParseException as pe:
    print ("Did not Match: ", pe)

print ("results:",  match)
```

which results in:
('results:', ([(['1', '39.75'], {})], {}))

I am expecting each number before the parenthesis, and the number in the parenthesis, for each occurrence.

Can someone please help me with this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'nums' is not defined in your code example.

Comment: `Word("0-100")` will only match words with "0", "1", and "-" in them, so it will match "1", but not "2". Try `Word(nums)` intead.

Comment: Also, consider using the new `pyparsing_common.number` expression, which will match integers and floats without you having to build them yourself as in `floatNumber`.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Replacing with Word(nums) worked. I misinterpreted the 0-100 pattern. Also, cleaned up my code to use parsing_common.number.